# How to specify input locations parameter in dataflow pipeline?

Tags: regex, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow template, that I originally created via Dataprep. Now I want to move away from Dataprep and use just Dataflow and schedule jobs using Cloud Scheduler. In GC console in Dataflow -> Jobs -> Select Job is a feature "Import as pipeline", which I use to create a batch job pipeline.

In the multistep form I cannot get past specifying the input locations:

[image]

It wants me to specify locations matching this regex:

```
[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]*\{[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]*((.|\r|\n)*".*"[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]*:[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]*".*"(.|\r|\n)*){0}[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]*\}[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]*
```

I tried with:

```
{
    "location1": "project:bq_dataset.bq_table1",
    "location10": "project:bq_dataset.bq_table10",
    "location17": "project:bq_dataset.bq_table17"
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/rTUfHH/1

In fact as others pointed out in the comments, it seems that I can only input `{}`

[image]

Any ideas why that is?

More details:

The flow is quite simple:

[image]

Data is loaded from GCS, transformed and put into BigQuery.

The loading of data is parameterized:

[image]

Here is the dataflow template: https://gist.github.com/arturozz/68fc482dba53ee2ab45f08b768e2d7cb

Comment: Well, this regex only allows strings like  `{}` / ``{  }``.

Comment: I was thrown off by the `{0}` in the regex. Your string works if that was removed. How did you end up in that input text box that asks for "Input locations of the dataflow job"? Can you add more details on how to go to this input text box? It will be better if you can provide what kind of dataflow template. Is it classic, custom, flex? And what does the template does? Just so this could be easily reproduced by the community members.

Comment: @RiccoD I added some context. I also added the dataflow template.

Comment: If ever you can also try contacting [gcp support](cloud.google.com/support-hub) to confirm how to use this or if there could be possible workarounds. This is if you have an existing free trial or premium support.